# Cannot start live streaming to youtube after obfuscation

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-proguard

I have the following code that works fine before obfuscation

```
YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.List liveBroadcastsRequest =
                                mYouTube.liveBroadcasts().list("id,snippet,contentDetails,status");
liveBroadcastsRequest.setMine(true);
liveBroadcastsRequest.setBroadcastType("persistent");
LiveBroadcastListResponse broadcastResponse = liveBroadcastsRequest.execute();
List<LiveBroadcast> broadcasts = broadcastResponse.getItems();
LiveBroadcast broadcast = broadcasts.get(0);
```

But in release version with obfuscation the last line of the code throws the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap cannot be cast to com.google.api.services.youtube.model.LiveBroadcast
```

I suppose that the issue happens because my obfuscation somehow breaks gson deserialization in google api, but I cannot find how to modify my proguard rules to make it working.

Current obfuscation rules

```
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.api.services.youtube.model.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Found a correct answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254625/proguard-configuration-when-using-android-studios-google-cloud-endpoints-templa)

I needed to keep the com.google.api.client.util.Key annotation from obfuscation.

```
-keepclassmembers class * {
  @com.google.api.client.util.Key <fields>;
}
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault
```

Thanks anyway.